# What's the time complexity of list access in Python?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I'm trying to make a python function as fast as I can. Let's suppose I have a prime list and I'm calling `primes[i]` n times for the same `i`.

I've the intuition that from a certain value of n, it becomes faser to keep the value of `primes[i]` in a variable.

I made some tries by comparing the two following implementations, and I can't figure out which one is the fastest. It looks like time access to `primes[i]` depends on a lot of factor.

**1st implementation**

```
while n != 1:
            p = primes[i]
            if n % p == 0:
                n = n // p
                factorization.append(p)
            else:
                i += 1
```

**2nd implementation**

```
while n != 1:
            if n % primes[i] == 0:
                n = n // primes[i]
                factorization.append(primes[i])
            else:
                i += 1
```

Is there any rule to know from how many calls it becomes interesting to keep the value of an element of a list in a variable ?

Comment: The whole idea of a list is that it has constant time access.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: _I can’t figure out which one is the fastest._ Have you done any benchmarking?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `primes[i]` is done in constant time, `O(1)`. What that means is that the time needed to read `primes[i]` does not increase as the `primes` becomes bigger and that it does not increase when `i` becomes bigger.
*In layman's terms: it's damn fast!*

Then again, accessing a local variable `p` is still faster than accessing `primes[i]`, because the latter has to look up and call the `__getitem__` implementation of the `primes` object. Therefore caching a value in a local variable instead of looking up a list twice is marginally faster.

On the other hand, caring about marginal speed improvements is meaningless compared to reducing algorithm complexity. For the problem of finding prime numbers, you should focus on finding a smart algorithm rather than on improving built-in-list access times.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a benchmark

```
import time

start = time.time()
while n != 1:
        p = primes[i]
        if n % p == 0:
            n = n // p
            factorization.append(p)
        else:
            i += 1
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

do the same for implementation 2 and compare.

And also, try doing it in google colab or any other external machine for better results.